# how can i get the sinf MATH functions answer in DEGREE?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

For example,

- sin 33.35 = 0.5523 in degree
- sin 33.35 = 0.9347 in radian

As Xcode gives answers by default in radian. 
So is there any way to get answer in degree ???

Comment: You can always convert radians to degrees easily...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you multiply radians by a constant, `180/pi`, to get degrees. That's because there are `2 * pi` radians in a complete circle of 360 degrees (so half a circle is `pi` radians and 180 degrees).

Just keep in mind that's a conversion you have to apply to the *input* of the sine function (the angle), not the output (which is a length).

The `pi` constant can be used by including `math.h` and using the `M_PI` symbol.

Answer (score 5):

A full circle in degrees exists of 360 degrees, and a full circle in radians is 2*pi. So, to convert radians to degrees, you divide by pi and multiply by 180.

```
radians * 180 / M_PI
```

If you would convert from degrees to radians, for example to provide degrees for a animation, use this:

```
degrees * M_PI / 180
```

I am using #DEFINEs for this myself:

```
#define DEGREES(radians)((radians)*180/M_PI)
#define RADIANS(degree)((degree)*M_PI/180)
```

Simply use by saying *RADIANS(degree)* or *DEGREES(radians)* in any part of your code, where you replace the *degree* and *radians* by the degree or radian value you had. This also keeps it more readable in my opinion if you are not used to radians.

Comment: your _description_ is right, `divide by pi and multiply by 180`, but your _formula_ doesn't match that: `radians / 180 * M_PI`. It should be `radians * 180 / M_PI`. Likewise, the reverse operation should be `degrees * M_PI / 180`.

Comment: Whoops! Typo indeed. Thanks for notifying me!

Answer (score 2):

Get the value in radians, then do:

```
CGFloat degrees = (radians * 180) / M_PI;
```

M_PI is a #define located in math.h.

Comment: I think you meant get the value in radians

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, the Objective-C language is a proper superset of C, which includes multiplication and division operators.